# Why is the move constructor called here?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Here is a code sample from a C++ quiz:

```
#include <iostream>
struct X {
    X(const char *) { std::cout << 1; }
    X(const X &) { std::cout << 2; }
    X(X &&) { std::cout << 3; }
};

X f(X a) {
    return a;
}

X g(const char * b) {
    X c(b);
    return c;
}

int main() {
    f("hello");
    g("hello");
}
```

What will be the output of the program?

I think  this way:

1. `f(X a)` is called, and the constructor implicitly converts `const char*` to X, so **the output is 1**
2. As we don't have an object to store the return value in, the return value is discarded, **no output**
3. `g(const char*)` is called, and `X c(b)` `X(const char*)` **The output is 1**
4. The return value is one more time discarded - **no output**

So the answer is 11. The answer which is given to the quiz is 131. The answer, which I get with g++ 4.4.4-13 is 121.

It is said that this code was compiled with this command:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -O -pthread
```

Where does the middle number come from? And why can it be 3 or 2?

Comment: Copy elision (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) is not mandatory. You cannot rely on this optimization. So the return statements output nothing cannot be relied upon.

Comment: Who wrote this as a "quiz"? This program can validly print four different outputs.

Comment: @T.C. It is something called C++ pub quiz at ACCU 2014 year

Comment: Don't forget that gcc 4.4 is a 2009 compiler, so implicit move on return was not there yet.

Comment: How can gcc 4.4 even accept `-std=c++11`? The only thing it knows is `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: @Ruslan yes, I compile with -std=c++0x and get 121. Quiz owners compile it with newer gcc, I think, and get 131.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In theory, this can print any of `131`, `13313`, `1313`, and `1331`. It's pretty silly as a quiz question.

- `f("hello");`:

  - "hello" is converted to a temporary `X` via the converting constructor, prints `1`.
  - The temporary `X` is used to initialize the function argument, calls the move constructor, prints `3`. This can be elided.
  - `x` is used to initialize the temporary return value, calls the move constructor, prints `3`. It's a function parameter, so no elision is allowed, but the return is an implicit move.
- `g("hello");`

  - "hello" is used to construct `c` via the converting constructor, prints `1`.
  - `c` is used to initialize the temporary return value, calls the move constructor, prints `3`. This can be elided.

Remember that functions always have to construct the thing they return, even if it's just discarded by the calling code.

As to printing `2`, that's because the ancient compiler you are using doesn't implement the implicit-move-when-returning-a-local-variable rule.

Comment: Is there a reason why a temporary has to be used (and possibly elided) for initialising the parameter of `f`? Why cannot the parameter be initialised directly from the argument?

Comment: @Angew Argument passing is copy-initialization. (Insert lengthy quote from [dcl.init]/17.6.2 here)

Comment: Thanks, [dcl.init]/15 is what I missed.

Comment: `11` can also be the result, if the compiler performs the NRVO. Or am I wrong?

Comment: @BЈовић No, you can't NRVO with a function parameter.

Comment: @T.C. Any special reason? I thought it is up to compiler to apply NRVO, but is free not to do it.

Comment: @BЈовић The standard just doesn't allow eliding a copy/move from a function parameter. Apparently because nobody figured out how to do it, so there's no motivation to make it allowed.

Answer (score 3):

[Copy elision](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) applies to the `return` statement in `g`, and possibly elsewhere. Quoted from cppreference:

> Copy elision is the only allowed form of optimization that can change
>   the observable side-effects. Because some compilers do not perform
>   copy elision in every situation where it is allowed (e.g., in debug
>   mode), programs that rely on the side-effects of copy/move
>   constructors and destructors are not portable.

So, to your example code, the output cannot be reliably predicted across different implementations.

Comment: Copy elision does not apply to the return in `f`.

Comment: @T.C. Oops, it is the parameter.